# How to properly close an action-sheet in Foundation Apps?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-apps

I have the exact same action sheet as in the example:

```
<div zf-action-sheet="">
  <div zf-as-button="" title="I'm an Action Sheet"></div>
  <div zf-as-content="" position="bottom">
    <p>Tap to share</p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Mail</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I tell Foundation Apps to close the action sheet when clicking on the links? I'd rather not name my action sheet if possible. From the docs it seems I should be able to just add `zf-hide=""` or `zf-close=""` to the links but neither work.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps/blob/95021ecff8d71a72c121b809d2daa6e4537bd034/js/angular/components/actionsheet/actionsheet.js#L52) it looks like by default it will close only if you click outside of it. And from [this](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps/blob/95021ecff8d71a72c121b809d2daa6e4537bd034/js/angular/components/actionsheet/actionsheet.js#L100) I think you have to name your action sheet within its `id` attribute. Then you can use `zf-close` inside your *links*.

This worked for me but the `href` attribute will be ignored and the *link* won't take you any where unless you use `ui-sref` instead :

```html
<div id="MyActionSheet" zf-action-sheet="">
  <div zf-as-button="" title="I'm an Action Sheet"></div>
  <div zf-as-content="" position="bottom">
    <p>Tap to share</p>
    <ul>
      <li><a zf-close="MyActionSheet" href="#">Twitter</a></li>
      <!-- 'href' attribute will be ignored so this is same as href="#"-->
      <li><a zf-close="MyActionSheet" href="/Facebook">Facebook</a></li>
      <!-- this will take you to the 'mail' page -->
      <li><a zf-close="MyActionSheet" ui-sref="mail">Mail</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```